# IE not clearing select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

i am using a simple piece of jquery to clear the contents of the select in a form, but in iE all versions, the select is not clearing. it is ok in FF, just not doing it in IE. can anyone see where i have gone wrong with this? i have posted the relevant part of the code. thanks

UPDATE:

what i am trying to achieve is when a form is submitted the inputs are cleared and the select/option returns to it default state like when the page was loaded.

Answer if it will help anyone else: $("select").prop('selectedIndex', 0);

```
/*Show submitted*/
//$(".done").show(500).slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
$(".done").html("<div id=\"boxSuccess\">Message sent successfully!</div><br />");
/*Clear input values*/
$("input").val("");
/*Clear slelect values*/
$("select").val("");
$(".done").fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000);
```

Comment: Is the empty string really the value of an `<option>` tag under the `<select>`?

Comment: @pointy sorry, do understand your comment? thanks

Comment: Setting the `<select>` value to "" means, "make the `<option>` whose value is "" be the current selection."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single-selection `<select>` element can't really be "cleared"; some `<option>` in it must be showing. What you could do to make sure that (for example) the first option is showing is

```
$('select').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; // or $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

*edit* — a look at the jQuery (1.5.2) source tells me that when the searched-for value can't be found as the value (or, if no "value" attribute, the text) of an option, then it sets the "selectedIndex" to -1.  A quick jsfiddle should show what effect that has in IE.

*edit again* — a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/zfc3S/) suggests that IE doesn't pay attention to the "selectedIndex" being set to -1.

*more* [Here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8512) is a relevant jQuery bug report.  Personally I don't think it's really a bug in the case of a single-select dropdown.  For a multi-select I could see an argument, though it's always possible to do:

```
$('select option').prop('selected', false);
```

to de-select everything in a multi-select.  Doesn't work for a single-selection element however because, again, that doesn't really make sense.  The element will *always* cause the value of one of its options to be submitted with the form, so it really can't be "cleared" unless one of the options has an empty value.

*even more* — If one of your options has the "defaultSelected" attribute (or property), then you could make it be the selected option with:

```
$('select option').each(function() {
  this.selected = this.defaultSelected;
});
```

Comment: IIRC, `element.selectedIndex = -1` should work in all supported versions of IE. (edit: and it does - http://jsfiddle.net/N36fL/)

Comment: @Andy E yes I agree, though it's been a while since I tried. I'm booting my IE VM to check :-)

Comment: @Andy E well it doesn't work for me in IE8 ... try it with more than one `<option>` and make sure none has an empty value, like [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfc3S/).

Comment: @pointy this seems to be a problem with different browsers on multi select elements. i was under the impression that with jquery 1.6 which i am running there was now a standard for this element? hmm will need to dig further. must be an answer. i cannot believe that this problem is still out on a limb.

Comment: Well there's an easy workaround - just set "selectedIndex" yourself.

Comment: @pointy tried this: $('#select option').each(function() {     this.selected= this.defaultSelected; }); this failed in IE?

Comment: and this: $("select option").attr("selectedIndex"); and this: $("select").attr("selectedIndex"); still IE not playing ball..grrrr

Comment: **Look at the code in my answer.** It works.  Don't use ".attr()", use ".prop()".

Comment: @pointy your code already contained a prop that you posted earlier. what code are your referring to?

Comment: **Don't use ".attr()" to set the property, use ".prop()".** There are two ways of doing it mentioned directly above these comments in my answer that will set the `<select>` to have the first option (index 0) be selected.  If you don't like 0, make it something else.

Comment: @pointy must have crossed posted. this works in ie. $("select").prop('selectedIndex', 0); yippeeee hmm better test in ff.

Comment: @Pointy: huh, didn't expect that.  I tested in quirks mode (IE 5.5) and standards mode on IE 9.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a very well-defined thing, but setting the "selectedIndex" (or the "selected" attribute of the first option) seems like a more above-board way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are setting the value on a collection of objects i think. 
I'd do it this way:

```
$("select").add("input").each(function(){
     $(this).val("");
});
```

instead of

```
/*Clear input values*/
$("input").val("");
/*Clear slelect values*/
$("select").val("");
```

This is valid (obviously) only if you have an option with value='' and this is what you want to reset the select to. Like

```
 <option value=''>Select a value</option>
```

Comment: The ".val()" method already knows how to operate on a collection; it's got an "each()" loop built into it, in other words.  Thus this approach is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this fiddle in IE and it works http://jsfiddle.net/cJh5h/. i always used that code on IE withouth problems.

Answer (score 1):

`$("select").val("");` should merely set as selected whichever item has `""` as its value. If you want to actually remove the items, you want something like `$("select option").remove();`

Comment: that completely removes the list. i just need to show deafult list when form is submitted. this works $("input").val(""); in IE $("select").val("");  this doesn't.